# How can i share an auth token over multiple gatling scenarios?

Tags: session-variables, gatling

i'm using gatling 2.0.3, and i'm looking to execute a single chain and store the auth token before running some complex scenario's. But i can't find a way to share the token across scenarios with out first executing the auth chain and writing it to a file, to be picked up by a feeder. Is there a correct way to do this?

```
before{
    scenario_get_auth.inject(
        //make auth call and save to file for feeder
    )
}.protocols(default_http)

setUp{
    scenario_load_one.inject(
       constantUsersPerSec(10).during(test_duration_secs)
    )
    scenario_load_two.inject(
       constantUsersPerSec(1-).during(test_duration_secs)
    )
}.protocols(default_http)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A similar question has been answer recently on [our mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gatling/bfpKd_9d6gk).

Basically, you have to use a global ConcurrentHashMap.

Comment: Thanks this is just what i was looking for, I just couldn't find it from googling. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for something similar but could not use Concurrent HashMap as @Stephane suggested as my access tokens were expiring after an hour.

Here is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/krisnik/32e5bebb23b60ad128f33f122ea16987) of code snippet where I have created a wrapper on top of Guava Cache taking dependency on [ScalaCache](https://github.com/cb372/scalacache).

This allows us to expire the cache entries before the actual token get expired. So, we need not add additional handling of 401 status codes in Simulations.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I've added a comment in your gist. Also, Guava Cache is a dead project. AFAIK, creator left Google, nobody took over his work on Guava Cache, and he created Caffeine (https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine). There's a Scala wrapper: https://github.com/blemale/scaffeine

Comment: Thanks Stephane. I can take the switch to Caffeine.